# SQL Server 2008 - get current LOCK_ESCALATION on particular table

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, lock-escalation, locking

Is there a way to find the current setting for LOCK_ESCALATION on particular table? Can it be found through system views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, [you'd have to look using SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286%28SQL.105%29.aspx), the `Lock:Escalation` event

Esclation information isn't in [sys.dm_tran_locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx) or it's predecessors

Answer (score 3):

I understand you want to know the setting.

This is easy: just run the query below. The possible values are TABLE, AUTO and DISABLE.

```
select t.lock_escalation_desc from sys.tables t where t.name = 'your_table';
```

TABLE is the default mode. On this mode, the lock goes from both PAGE or ROW directly to TABLE level.

DISABLE can be useful in some scenarios, but use it carefully.

AUTO includes an intermediate level between ROW/PAGE and TABLE: it's the PARTITION level. Instead of locking the whole table, it only locks the needed partition.

Source: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sql-server-2008-partition-level-lock-escalation-details-and-examples/